# How to print Section Symbol ( § ) in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, stored-procedures

XML

```
<RevisionHistory>(R.S., D.C., § 1; June 11, 1878, 20 Stat. 102, ch. 180, § 1.)</RevisionHistory>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:value-of select="RevisionHistory" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Output:

```
§ = i want output this symbol
� = but wrong symbol shown
```

How to print Section Symbol ( § ) in XML using XSLT?

Comment: It's most likely an encoding error. Those are hard to be sure of. We would need to be able to download your unmodified XML and XSLT files from somewhere to check if encodings are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML document is expected (but not required) to use an XML declaration at the begin of the document, stating the encoding used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8858-1"?>
```

In the absence of an XML declaration, UTF-8 or other out-of-band agreed encoding is assumed.

To exclude the possibility of encoding issues (where your XML is stored in non-UTF-8 encoding yet isn't exposing its encoding via an XML declaration) you could change your XML to use the `&#167;` character entity reference for the section sign:

```
<RevisionHistory>(R.S., D.C., &#167; 1; June 11, 1878, 20 Stat. 102, ch. 180, &#167; 1.)</RevisionHistory>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main possibilities for why this is going wrong.

(a) the character in the input document is encoded using a different encoding from the one that the XML parser thinks it is using. For example, perhaps the character is encoded in iso-8859-1 but the XML parser thinks it is encoded in utf-8.

(b) the character in the result document is correctly encoded, but the software that you are using to display the result document doesn't understand that encoding.

To investigate this you need to establish the binary code that is used internally to represent this character in both the input and the output documents. To determine that, use a tool such as a hex editor.

Check that the input file has an XML declaration giving the correct encoding. If there isn't one, this could well be the source of the trouble. If there is one, check that it's correct.

Then do the same for the output file.

Check what software you are using to display the output file. See if different software displays the character differently. You might need to change how the display software is configured. If the display software is a web browser, you may need to check or change what the HTTP headers say about the character encoding of the document sent to the browser.

Finally, get rid of that disable-output-escaping attribute. It only adds extra complications and possible sources of error.